# Is there anyway to check if an element was clicked in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway in javascript to correctly identify if an element was clicked?

Something like...

```
const clicked = document.getElementById("myElement").click() ? true : false
```

To then be used something like...

```
if(clicked){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't track that by default. Attach an event listener to the object and keep track of that information yourself.

Comment: Add a class to the button that is clicked.

Comment: @deceze that makes more sense now, was curious to see if there was an out of the box solution! Thanks bud

Comment: It's not clear what you expect `if(clicked)` to do.  Every time it's clicked do x?  (assign an event handler)  When I do y check if it has been clicked at some point in the past?  (use an event handler that sets a variable when it's clicked, and read that variable when you do y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the previous click occurrence in a global variable as followings:

```js
var isClicked = false;

document.getElementById("myElem").addEventListener("click",function(){
   isClicked = true;
})

function checkClick(){
  console.log('Is Clicked?', isClicked)
}
```

```css
#myElem{
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="myElem">Click</div>

<button onclick="checkClick()">Check Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have one boolean variable which meant the state of the button click.
So, you define the `onClick` method and set the variable to true inside the onClick method.

```
var clicked = false;
...
function onClick(event) {
  clicked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addEventListener` on an HTML element in JavaScript. It takes two arguments: the event type and the event handler. In this case, the type is `click`, and you want to set a boolean variable if that's right?

```js
let clicked = false;
document.getElementById('myElement').addEventListener('click', () => {
clicked = true;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try :

```
if(document.getElementById('button').clicked == true)
{
   alert("button was clicked");
}

<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="enter"/>
```